# nginx www redirect except other subdomains

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, cloud-foundry

Probably yet another nginx redirect question... couldn't find the answer, so:

How do I redirect http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com but do not rewrite any subdomain http://*.domain.com given the cloudfoundry nginx configuration which contains this server definition:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
}
```

I tried this configuration

```
server {
     server_name domain.com
     rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
}
```

but am getting infinite redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
server_name  _;
```

with

```
server_name *.domain.com;
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I was trying not to modify any original configuration files. But still, why would "_" not catch all other domains?

Comment: @HTTPeter Underscore symbol in Nginx has actually not a "any domain" meaning, but rather an opposite - i.e. "_" stands for "some-never-matching-domain". So when a request comes with host=subdomain.domain.com, Nginx checks the first server{} section (server_name domain.com) and it does not match, then it checks the second server{} section (server_name _) - it does NOT match too, which means that the FIRST server section is used as a default one.

Comment: @HTTPeter You also can either switch two server sections so that one with "_" would be the first section, or explicitly define second section as default with "listen 80 default_server". That will be fine in case you do not have to handle any other requests (not related to *.domain.com at all) that may occasionally fall into "server_name _".

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com
    return 301 http://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    ...
}
```

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html